# C# Regular Expression: Search the first 3 letters of each name

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Does anyone know how to say I can get a regex (C#) search of the first 3 letters of a full name?

Without the use of (`.*`)

I used (`.**`)but it scrolls the text far beyond the requested name, or
if it finds the first condition and after 100 words find the second condition he return a text that is not the look, so I have to limit in number of words.
Example: `\s*(?:\s+\S+){0,2}\s*`

I would like to ignore names with less than 3 characters if they exist in name.

Search any name that contains the first 3 characters that start with:

```
'Mar Jac Rey' (regex that performs search)
```

Should match:

- **Mar**ck **Jac**obs L. S. **Rey**nolds
- **Mar**cus **Jac**obine **Rey**s
- **Mar**oon **Jac**queline by **Rey**ils

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your input/output and regex are confusing, please edit and rephrase the question.

Comment: I am using C# Language

Comment: changed the text for better comprehension

Comment: As per [this discussion on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed?cb=1) regarding questions asking for "a regex to do X", this question is flagged as a duplicate of [the canonical regex reference question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zero or more quantifier (`*`) is 'greedy' by default—that is, it will consume as many characters as possible in order to finding the remainder of the pattern. This is why `Mar.*Jac` will match the *first* `Mar` in the input and the *last* `Jac` and everything in between.

One potential solution is just to make your pattern 'non-greedy' (`*?`). This will make it consume as few characters as possible in order to match the remainder of the pattern.

```
Mar.*?Jac.*?Rey
```

However, this is not a great solution because it would still match the various name parts regardless of what other text appears in between—e.g. `Marcus Jacobine Should Not Match Reys` would be a valid match.

To allow only whitespace or at most 2 consecutive non-whitespace characters to appear between each name part, you'd have to get more fancy:

```
\bMar\w*(\s+\S{0,2})*\s+Jac\w*(\s+\S{0,2})*\s+Rey\w*
```

The pattern `(\s+\S{0,2})*\s+` will match any number of non-whitespace characters containing at most two characters, each surrounded by whitespace. The `\w*` after each name part ensures that the entire name is included in that part of the match (you might want to use `\S*` instead here, but that's not entirely clear from your question). And I threw in a word boundary (`\b`) at the beginning to ensure that the match does not start in the middle of a 'word' (e.g. `OMar` would not match).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this regular expression to check if it is true and is case insensitive

```
@"^[Mar|Jac|Rey]{3}"
```

Less specific:

```
@"^[\w]{3}"
```

Comment: I can not use a regex "OR" (Mar|Jac|Rey) because the 3 letters of each name are mandatory and it should be (the three).

Comment: What about the suggested '\w' ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the first three letters of every words of at least three characters words you could use something like :

```
((?<name>[\w]{3})\w+)+
```

And enable ExplicitCapture when initializing your Regex.

It will return you a serie of Match named "name", each one of them is a result.

Code sample :

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"((?<name>[\w]{3})\w+)+", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = regex.Matches("Marck Jacobs L. S. Reynolds");
```

If you want capture also 3 characters words, you can replace the last "\w" by a space. In this case think to handle the last word of the phrase.